# how to Handle Subdomain in rails with unicorn, and nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unicode, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I followed a simple railscasts episode on [multitenant](http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes) 
now all tenants in my app enters their subdomain which works locally on my dev syatem but wen i try this same process on my vps system, the browser says cannot find the server.

I have connected a domain to my ip and modified my nginx file and still no hope

once a user enters his subdomain, the request does not get to my rails app.

any idea on this or i might not be getting it right. Thanks

my nginx_unicorn_file

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.<%= application %>.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name shopnany.com *.shopnany.com;
  root <%= current_path %>/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had no problem doing this. First you need to create an A record in any DNS provider that you are using. for example create a DNS record:

it.shopnany.com

Then you'll have to update your nginx config template for this particular deployment. It can be as follows:

```
upstream unicorn_<%= application %> {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.<%= application %>.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name it.shopnany.com;
  root <%= current_path %>/public;

  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_<%= application %>;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

This worked for me. Now I have two different applications running on my www and it subdomains.

Comment: After a deep research, i figured out that i had to create a wildcard for the c record * with this, clients can create multiple subdomains without me knowing so i dont have to create c records for individual  client. if the main app cannot find the subdomain it handles the request to the main app. very simple